# Выделить только цифры кроме тех, где буквы и (_) до и после

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно составить регулярное выражение, чтобы выделить только те цифры, перед и после, которыми нет букв и символа нижнего прочерка (_) ?

Например, эти цифры нужно выделить (кроме спец.символов (,&&.) до и после):

```
,0

12

123

,43,

.01

&&50

100 &&
```

А эти цифры не нужно выделять:

```
 bfr_ind01
 hello_03
 02_qwerty
```

Сейчас стоит такой вариант:

```
{ regex: /,[0-9]/gm, css: 'number' }
```

Пробовал что-то вроде этого и различные вариации:

```
 { regex: /(\W\s)[0-9](\W\s)/gm, css: 'number' }
```

...но так ничего толкового и не вышло. Частично только добиваюсь результата. Подскажите, как правильно.

Comment: вы не забыли случайно `^` и `$`  в вашем регулярном выражении?

Comment: К сожалению это не помогает. Покажите Ваш вариант.

Comment: ReinRaus,
Результат в первой группе? Что это значит? Попробовал Ваш вариант, но полностью проблема не решена. Например, запятые (,) или точка с запятой (;) рядом с цифрами тоже окрашиваются. Исключены цифры только из этого варианта bfr_ind_01_.

Comment: Подсказали ещё вот такой вариант:

/(^|[^0-9A-zА-яЁё_]{1})([0-9]+)([^0-9A-zА-яЁё_]{1}|$)/g

но запятые (,) и точки с запятой (;) не исключаются до и после цифр.

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись без callback (так Вам посоветовали в другом форуме, но наш форум лучше :) ):

```
/\b\d+\b/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/qP3zN3/1

Так это будет выглядеть у Вас в коде:

```
{ regex: /\b\d+(?!\w)/i, css: 'number' }
```

Comment: «Результат в первой группе» означает, что если Вы хотите например подсветить найденные цифры, то надо делать такую замену:  

    text.replace(expression, "<span style=\"color:red\">\1</span>");
Или вроде того в зависимости от способа где Вы применяете выражение.

Comment: Я бы дал выражение, которое не захватит лишние символы, но в JavaScript это невозможно из-за отсутствия negative lookahead. Все могло бы быть так:  
    /(?<=[^a-zа-я_]|^)\d+(?=[^a-zа-я_]|$)/i

Comment: Спасибо. На другом форуме тоже написали, что в JS это невозможно. Придётся или отказаться от цифр в именах переменных или просто делать пробелы между спец.символами и цифрами. Ну или отказаться от подсветки цифр в конце концов. Будут чёрными, как имена переменных. )))

Comment: Приведите код непосредственно в контексте которого будет применяться выражение.

Comment: Спасибо за то, что уделили время на мой вопрос. Вопрос решили на другом форуме. Там это было удобнее тем, что можно обмениваться файлами.

Если интересно, вот ссылка на обсуждение: http://www.cyberforum.ru/javascript/thread734240-page2.html#post3870723

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй такой вариант:

```
(?:[^\w_]|^|\b)(\d+)(?:[^\w_]|$|\b)
```

[пример](http://www.pcre.ru/eval/(%3F%3A%5B%5E%5Cw_%5D%7C%5E%7C%5Cb)(%5Cd%2B)(%3F%3A%5B%5E%5Cw_%5D%7C%24%7C%5Cb)%40%3D%23%3D%40101%40%3D%23%3D%40%20bfr_ind01%262a%3B%20hello_03%262a%3B%2002_qwerty%262a%3B%2C0%262a%3B12%262a%3B123%262a%3B%2C43%2C%262a%3B%26%2650%20100%20%26%26%262a%3B%262a%3B.01/)

Comment: Не выходит корректно. Почему-то запятые, если рядом с цифрами, тоже захватывает.

Comment: @tol64 так ты бери каждое второе значение ;)

Comment: Покажите, как это? На одном форуме уже написали, что эта задача не решаема в JavaScript. )))